# Checkbox array in ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

In Controller wow do I get an array of checkboxes which are unchecked and defined in view page. In the view page i have an array of checkboxes with corresponding images. SO I need to get these array of checkboxes in a controller and check if it is checked and then pass the corresponding images with items checked to the view page again.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you name the checkboxes in the view. The values will be available in the controller in the `params[]` hash/array. To see how how the values are formatted looks the server log when to submit the form and you will see all submitted params.

Comment: I believe I would get the checbox array in controller as params if only the checkbox is checked. I need to get the checbox array of unchecked one also.

Comment: What i actually want is that in my view page there are checkboxes and corresponding images listed. So when i selects the images and click on Continue button it will go to a js function and then do some processing on selected images. So I need to send only the selected images as params to that JS function. So I think the good way would be to pass these selected images from the view to controller and then do a check if it is selected and then return the result to the view back again to pass as an params to js func

Comment: So I think the good way would be to pass all images anc checkboxes from the view to controller and then do a check if it is selected and then return the result to the view back again to pass as an params to js func